# Can I use java-8 compiled project/library in a java-11 spring boot 2 project?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Maybe a stupid question, I am in a process of upgrading bunch of our frameworks/libraries to java 11. I have this 1 project (Project Dep) that is a dependency of another project (Proj X). Both are java 8 and to be upgraded to Java 11.

However, both projects are big and might take days to be done, the Proj D is considerably larger (and used by a lot of devs) than Project X using it. I am thinking just upgrading the Proj X to java 11 and spring boot 2, and use the java 8 version of Proj D.

Will that work? I am asking just to have a clear path on what should I do in order and prioritize.

Comment: Java is backwards compatible. A project compiled in a lower version should be able to run with a higher version. But there are some dependencies that could ruin your week. I'm in the process of upgrading myself, and Java 8 -> Java 11 clashes frequently with some of our imported libraries. Up until now I've always been able to find a solution on the internet to find alternative libraries that DO work with Java 11 and above

Comment: So basically the java 8 compiled library MIGHT not work when using it on a running java 11 project?

Comment: compiled with lower version and running in a higher version should be no problem. My dependency-problems are situated around the fact that I also need the project to be able to build in a higher version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use the Project D(dependency Java 8) in Project X(Java 11) also Check for deprecation of packages in Java 11 and make sure you update the deprecated packages in Java 8 Project. Or If you want to upgrade both to Java 11 not a problem. Consider your time and Upgrading is always a better option.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what version the project is in, it matters what version the JVM that will run it is. It must be at least the version of any of the dependencies.